# Compile-time type safety for promises in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular-cli, typescript-generics

Fresh project created with ng cli.
When compiling/serving with with "ng serve", the compiling process doesn't catch type errors on the generic arguments of promises. The errors are instead thrown (as expected) for my own generic types.

```
export class MyThing<T> {
    thing: T;

    constructor(t: T) {
        this.thing = t;
    }
}

// throws an error (expected, MyThing<number> is not assignable to MyThing<string>)
export function throwsAsExpected(): MyThing<string> {
    return new MyThing<number>(4);
}

// DOESNT throw an error (I expected, Promise<number> is not assignable to Promise<string>)
// maybe there's something 
export function doesntThrow(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(42);
    });
}
```

For the above code i just get this:

```
ERROR in E:/src/poc-gui/src/app/services/ws/whatever.service.ts (20,9): Type 'MyThing<number>' is not assignable to type 'MyThing<string>'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.)
```

Which is expected but it doesn't catch the error on the promise function.
Suspiciously, Sublime (with ts plugin), shows the error, as expected.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is is possible to retain compile-time type safety for promises or am I missing something?

Comment: What typescript version are you compiling with?

Comment: $ node_modules/.bin/tsc --version
Version 2.0.10

Comment: And the Promise is from?

Comment: Supposedly the standard Typescript promises. I don't have any specific import/require for the Promise object.

Comment: Could it be that the compiler only throws the *first* error?

Comment: I don't think so. Multiple errors are reported as i expect.